# Django FilteredSelectMultiple widget rendered with bootstrap

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms, django-admin

I am trying to replicate the `FilteredSelectMultiple` widget used in the admin of the django apps.
But my widget is rendered very different

[image: My rendered widget]

The widget in the admin using [django-suit](http://djangosuit.com) or [django_admin_bootstrapped](https://github.com/django-admin-bootstrapped/django-admin-bootstrapped) is rendered with bootstrap:

[image: Wdiget rendered in the admin]

I define my widget and media the forms.py:

```
class ProcFTPForm(forms.ModelForm):
      id_archivo = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Archivo_Descarga.objects.all(),required=True,widget=FilteredSelectMultiple("Archivo",is_stacked=False))
      class Media:
       css = {'all':('/admin/css/widgets.css',),}
       js = ('/admin/jquery.js','/admin/jsi18n/')

      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super(ProcFTPForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          self.helper = FormHelper()

      class Meta:
            model = Lista_Archivos
```

And in the template I call the media files in this way:

```
{{ form.media }}
```

How can I render the `FilteredSelectMultiple` widget looking similar like the widget from the admin. 
In other words how can I render this widget using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

I am using [django-crispy-forms](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms) and the other widgets are rendered with bootstrap except the `FilteredSelectMultiple` widget

Any advice

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

[django-admin-bootstrapped](https://github.com/django-admin-bootstrapped/django-admin-bootstrapped) specifies styles to override django admin defaults i.e. like the file [overrides.css](https://github.com/django-admin-bootstrapped/django-admin-bootstrapped/blob/master/django_admin_bootstrapped/static/admin/css/overrides.css). The widget `FilteredSelectMultiple` use the css class `.selector` and your page should apply css selectors declared [from line 39 to 119 of overrides.css](https://github.com/django-admin-bootstrapped/django-admin-bootstrapped/blob/master/django_admin_bootstrapped/static/admin/css/overrides.css#L39-L119), so you will need to add its styles to your page, either by  changing your `Media` class in form:

```
class Media:
   css = {'all':('/admin/css/widgets.css', 'admin/css/overrides.css'),}
   js = ('/admin/jquery.js','/admin/jsi18n/')
```

or directly include it template:

```
<link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/css/overrides.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Hope this solve your problem

Comment: This worked for me (albeit, I had a different location for `overrides.css`)

Comment: Have a look @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858181/djangos-filteredselectmultiple-widget-only-works-when-logged-in/65831944#65831944